# jQuery AutoComplete com GenericHandler Error 404

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, autocompletar

Estou fazendo um *input* com função AutoComplete só que ao digitar ele retorna no console com erro 404. Segue o código:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#ListaNCM").autocomplete({ source: "ListaAuto.ashx" });
});
```

E o Generic Handler:

```
public class ListaAuto : IHttpHandler
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {          
        string input = context.Request.QueryString["term"];
        ProjetoEntities db = new ProjetoEntities();
        var Lista = db.Item.Where(x => x.DESCRICAO.Contains(input)).ToList();
        context.Response.Write(new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Lista));
    }
    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Se alguém conseguir me ajudar onde estou errando eu agradeço.

Comment: `autocomplete` é do jQuery ou alguma outra biblioteca? Eu não estou certo se é possível indicar como `source` algum endereço, como numa requisição ajax, porquê se for o caso, primeiro você pode fazer uma requisição ajax para depois preencher o *autocomplete* com o resultado.

Comment: @LucasCosta , #TemosOMesmoNome! e sim da para indicar url, é do jqury ui

Comment: da uma olhada aqui https://forums.asp.net/p/1533299/3717070.aspx

Comment: Não entendi muito bem o link que enviou @I'mBlueDaBaDee, então `ListaAuto.ashx` no source é válido? Em qual formato de retorno será preenchido os valores para autocomplete?

Comment: @LucasCosta o link é pro Brayan, hahaha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basicamente vamos criar uma rota pro seu `IHttpHandler`:

```
public class MeuRouteHandler : IRouteHandler //Carinha que vai "apontar" pra nossa rota
    {
        public IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext)
        {
            return new ListaAuto();
        }

        private class ListaAuto : IHttpHandler
        {
            public bool IsReusable { get { return false; } }

            public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
            {
                 string input = context.Request.QueryString["term"];

                 ProjetoEntities db = new ProjetoEntities();

                 var Lista = db.Item.Where(x => x.DESCRICAO.Contains(input))
                                    .Select(x => new { //autocomplete trabalha com label e value 
                                        label = x.DESCRICAO,//Aparece pro usuário
                                        value = x.ID//Valor 
                                    })
                                    .ToList();

                 context.Response.Write(new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Lista));
            }
        }
    }
```

No seu `Routes.cs` vamos mapear isso:

```
public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.ashx/{*pathInfo}");

            //Bixisse pra deixar a rota bonitinha (Eu aprovo u.u)
            routes.Add(new Route("Ncm/Autocomplete/{term}", new MeuRouteHandler()));
            //Suas outras configurações ->...
        }
    }
```

Agora seu `script` fica algo parecido com isso:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //Com nossa nova Rota
    $("#ListaNCM").autocomplete({ source: "Ncm/Autocomplete/{term}" });
});
```

Comment: Primeiramente obrigado kk, mas...Continua dando erro postei novamente o código de como ficou.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public class AutoCompletaNCM : IRouteHandler
{
    public IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        return new ListaAuto();
    }

    private class ListaAuto : IHttpHandler
    {
        public bool IsReusable { get { return false; } }

        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            string input = context.Request.QueryString["term"];

            ProjetoEntities db = new ProjetoEntities();

            var Lista = db.item.Where(x => x.DESCRICAO.Contains(input))
                               .Select(x => new
                               { //autocomplete trabalha com label e value 
                                   label = x.DESCRICAO,//Aparece pro usuário
                                   value = x.ID//Valor 
                               })
                               .ToList();

            context.Response.Write(new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Lista));
        }
    }

}
```

RouteConfig:

```
 routes.Add(new Route("Ncm/Autocomplete/{term}", new AutoCompletaNCM()));
```

Jquery:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        //Com nossa nova Rota
        $("#ListaNCM").autocomplete({ source: "Ncm/Autocomplete" });
    });
```

Então... Continua dando NotFound, ha algo de errado?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: coloca o erro q aparece no console, vamos ver pra onde ele ta mandando

Comment: pronto coloquei no post

Comment: Amigo consegui \o/ kk, apenas coloquei um {term} no source tbm..... source: "Ncm/Autocomplete/{term}"

Comment: Muito Obrigado pela ajuda

Comment: Denada kk, queres q eu bote na resposta?

Comment: Acho que seria interessante caso alguém precise futuramente, muito obrigado :D

Comment: #Feito , não precisa agradecer ^^